# Mysql query i can not solve

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a situation here to get data(i.e. fname, lname and count(jobid)) from two different table comparing their jobid, deliverymanid, pickupmanid and employeeid from job and employee table and combine it in one row.

This is the job table

```
jobid      pickupmanid      deliverymanid
-----   ----------------  ------------------
  1                1              2
  2                2              2
  3                1              1
```

This is the employee table

```
employeeid        fname         lname
------------   -----------  -------------
    1               ABC           XYZ
    2               LMN           OPR
```

This is how i should get output

```
employeeid   totalpickupjobs   totaldeliveryjobs       fname         lname
----------   ---------------   -----------------   -----------    -----------
    1               2               1                ABC            XYZ
    2               1               2                LMN            OPR
```

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: Is there any other table involved?

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam no there is nt

Comment: @CahitGungor  i can do this by running two separate count queries

Comment: are you also looking for an oracle solution for this?

Comment: Use union for both counts and then get results

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam would you write a query fr me using union?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT e.employeeid, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jobtable j
WHERE j.pickupmanid = e.employeeid) as totalpickupjobs,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jobtable j
WHERE j.deliverymanid = e.employeeid) as totaldeliveryjobs,
e.fname, e.lname
FROM employeetable e
```

Go [**Sql Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f2d36/1/0)

Comment: @AniketKarne: Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT 1 AS jobid,1 AS pickupmaid,  1 AS delivery_manid FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 2 AS jobid,2 AS pickupmaid,  2 AS delivery_manid FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 3 AS jobid,1 AS pickupmaid,  1 AS delivery_manid FROM dual ),
         y AS (SELECT 1 AS employeeid,'ABC' AS fname,  'XYZ' AS lname FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 2 AS employeeid,'LMN' AS fname,  'OPR' AS lname FROM dual )

SELECT y.employeeid as employee_id, 
        count(pickupmaid) as totalpickup, 
        count(delivery_manid) as totaldelivery, 
        y.fname as firstname, 
        y.lname as lastname
FROM y FULL OUTER JOIN x ON X.pickupmaid=y.employeeid group by y.employeeid, y.fname, y.lname;
```

Comment: This works for only two names i want it for all names i have it in my table there are 120 names

Answer (score 0):

use mysql `count` ,`inner join` or `group by`:-

```
select *,count(job.deliverymanid) from Job inner 
join Pickupman on Job.pickupmanid=Pickupman.pickupmanid 
group by deliverymanid
```

Comment: nope u did not get my question .. check the question again

Comment: select *,count(job.deliverymanid) from Job inner join Pickupman on Job.pickupmanid=Pickupman.pickupmanid group by deliverymanid

Comment: i want to count deliverymanid and pickupmanid from job table and i want to group them by pickupman.pickupmanid .. i have posted the answer table i want answer like that

Comment: select *,count(job.deliverymanid),count(job.pickupmanid) from Job inner join Pickupman on Job.pickupmanid=Pickupman.pickupmanid group by pickupmanid

Comment: select *,(select count(job.deliverymanid) from Job where Job.pickupmanid=Pickupman.pickupmanid) as pickupmanid_count,count(job.pickupmanid) from Job inner join Pickupman on Job.pickupmanid=Pickupman.pickupmanid group by pickupmanid

Comment: still results the count deliverymanid result is same as count pickupmanid

Comment: Please check the question I have rephrased it.